# Check all values of vlookup for certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a datatable like this in excel

```
CAT  | TYPE
foo  | first
foo  | none
bar  | none
baz  | none
```

I need a formula to say given a name is their a type of "first".
So for the sample data the formula will be true only when the given name is "foo".

I have tried doing multiple VLookups and using a helper column to get a unique name however this doesn't do what I want.

I feel like their will be a very elegant way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `VLOOKUP`,`IFERROR` and a logical operator `=` for this.

Assuming CAT/TYPE is column A/B use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("foo",A:B,2,FALSE)="first",FALSE)
```

You can replace `"foo"` with a cell reference.